# How would Starkiller Base function in the long term if it took entire Suns to charge up?

Tags: star-wars

Starkiller Base was made out of a Planet with it's super weapon being powered by draining the nearby sun.

But how would it work for the long term? could the planet actually move? if so how and what was the energy source for this?